# Process XML by chunks in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have a series of large XML files (~3GB each) that I'm trying to process. The rough format of the XML is

```
<FILE>
<DOC>
    <FIELD1>
        Some text.
    </FIELD1>
    <FIELD2>
        Some text. Probably some more fields nested within this one.
    </FIELD2>
    <FIELD3>
        Some text.
    </FIELD3>
    <FIELD4>
        Some text. Etc.
    </FIELD4>
</DOC>
<DOC>
    <FIELD1>
        Some text.
    </FIELD1>
    <FIELD2>
        Some text. Probably some more fields nested within this one.
    </FIELD2>
    <FIELD3>
        Some text.
    </FIELD3>
    <FIELD4>
        Some text. Etc.
    </FIELD4>
</DOC>
</FILE>
```

My current approach is (mimicking the code seen at http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm#incremental-parsing):

```
#Added this in the edit.
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.iterparse(xml_file)
tree = iter(tree)
event, root = tree.next()

for event, elem in tree:
    #Need to find the <DOC> elements
    if event == "end" and elem.tag == "DOC":
        #Code to process the fields within the <DOC> element. 
        #The code here mainly just iterates through the inner 
        #elements and extracts what I need
        root.clear()
```

This blows up, though, and uses all of my system memory (16GB). At first I thought it was the position of the `root.clear()` so I tried moving that out to after the if-statement, but that didn't seem to have any effect. Given this, I'm note quite sure how to proceed other than "get more memory."

**EDIT**:

Deleted the previous edit because it was wrong.

Comment: If there is that much data xml may not be the most efficient way to store it

Comment: have you tried using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de)?

Comment: Have you tried using [SAX](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.html)?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Consider one of the libraries like one of the above that allow you to parse XML files without loading the whole thing into memory, since it seems that all you need is to extract data.

Comment: @735Tesla, I agree. The data has been given to me, though.

Comment: @MattDMo, I had not, since it seems that the procedure is largely the same. I also haven't used SAX since I thought the whole document needed to be read into memory at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the code you've already written if you switch to `lxml` and do this to clear out the tree...

```
from lxml import etree
context = etree.iterparse(xmlfile)  # can also limit to certain events and tags
for event, elem in context:
    # do some stuff here with elem
    elem.clear()
    while elem.getprevious() is not None:
        del elem.getparent()[0]
```

I'm not claiming this is efficient, but it might get the job done.

Comment: The `elem.getprevious()` fails with an error that `elem` doesn't have the attribute of `getprevious`. I've also added more info in the edit to the OP.

Comment: Apologies, I checked my code and I am using `lxml`.  I have edited my response to reflect that.  There might be an equivalent, however, in `xml.etree`.

Comment: It looks like the `elem.clear()` has done it. I haven't had a chance to run through the entire file, but the memory usage looks like its holding steady.